# How to extract solutions to a Pell's equation satisfying certain congruences?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

I'm trying to solve $y^2=3x^2+3x+1$ for integers, which transforms into $(2y)^2-3(2x+1)^2=1$. I know how to solve pell's equation, but how can we extract only (odd,even) pair from the solutions of the diophantine equation $y^2-3x^2=1$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31118/integer-polynomials-taking-square-values/195614#195614

Answer (score 1):

There is a recursion, with each solution a linear combination of an earlier solution.  That should help decide which are even, which are odd.